# In Python 3 coding, how do I require a sprite to have three collisions prior to being removed?

Tags: python-3.x, collision-detection

I am working on a space invaders type game and I have it working in a manner such that it takes one bullet hit to kill an invader. What I am trying to do now is to change it so that it takes three bullet hits to kill an invader.

My current code is located here: https://github.com/clipovich/alien_invasion.git

If you run the code as posted, the game works fine to kill an alien using a single bullet hit.

Beginning with a working single bullet to kill game, here is what I have changed: (note: you can reproduce my changes by simply uncommenting lines 66 and 67 in the alien_invasion.py file.

```
# if self.aliens.settings.alien_hit_limit >= 0:
#    self.aliens.remove()
```

In the settings.py file, I have created

```
self.alien_hit_limit = 3
```

In the alien_invasion.py file, I have added:

```
if self.aliens.settings.alien_hit_limit >= 0:
self.aliens.remove()
```

to

```
def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
```

and now I receive the following error message:

> > ~/py/alien_invasion$ python3.8 alien_invasion.py pygame 1.9.6 Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "alien_invasion.py", line
> > 210, in 
> > ai.run_game()   File "alien_invasion.py", line 42, in run_game
> > self._update_bullets()   File "alien_invasion.py", line 57, in _update_bullets
> > self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()   File "alien_invasion.py", line 66, in _check_bullet_alien_collisions
> > if self.aliens.settings.alien_hit_limit >= 0: AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'settings'

I think my problem may be that I am trying to perform actions on individual aliens but using a group method. I am not sure though.

When fixed, the end result would be that an alien disappears after being hit three times, not once.

What do I need to do to correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing settings from "Group" submodule from pygame module. But you are attempting to access a attribute from "Settings" class from the settings.py file. So if you want to access "alien_hit_limit" attribute from "settings" object you should use "if self.settings.alien_hit_limit >= 0:" instead of "if self.aliens.settings.alien_hit_limit >= 0:" in line 66, to resolve the error you specified.

Comment: Did you run the code? If so, did it work for you? When I made the change that you recommended, aliens were still being killed with one hit. I then changed  the second True to False in order to prevent single hit kills but now my aliens are immortal.

Comment: I also think I need to improve the code that keeps track of how many times an alien has been hit.

Comment: I changed to the following but my aliens are still invincible: I changed to the following but my aliens are still invincible.  `collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, True, False)
if collisions:
    for alien in collisions.values():
        self.settings.alien_hit_limit -= 1
    for alien in collisions.values():
        if self.settings.alien_hit_limit <= 0:
            self.aliens.remove()`

Comment: @chadrick I have manged to pull off what you have tried to achieve. I will describe it in the answer section below.

Comment: Thank you so much! You spent a good deal of time on this to make it work. The finished problem is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not useful for having alien_hit_limit as a global attribute. Rather you should assign hit_point for each alien in the alien.py file:

[image]

Next you should change the `_check_bullet_alien_collisions()` method:
[image]

The `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` method return the list of the collided objects from the group you specified first in the function. (self.aliens). So it will return the list of aliens that have been hit by the bullet (in this case only one alien is returned hit by a bullet). So you reduce it's hitpoint when it's it and check if hitpoints have reduced to zero; in that case remove that alien from the alien list. By the way third parameter of the `pygame.sprite.groupcollide` method specify whether the object from the first group(in this case self.aliens) should be destroyed and the fourth parameter specify whether the object from the second group(in this case self.bullets) should be destroyed. So we do not destroy the alien right way so set the third parameter false but we want the bullet to be destroyed; so we set the fourth parameter to true.